# How to pass frame information via UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I try to implement iOS application.

I want to vertical split display, and upper half has horizontally slidable view.
But I can't set frame to each view that are held by each controller of UIPageViewController.
I try to set frame to view.frame of UIPageViewController, but it is not working.

How to set it? Or more suitable controller class?

Comment: You need to show your progress so far, and explain what is not working as you want. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is autolayout enabled? Even if you didn't add constraints manually it adds some layout constraints by itself. so it will ignore the setting of a frame. to solve this use `pageViewController.view. translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: Sorry I solve my problem. Change code on controller, from `self.view.addSubView(myView)` to `self.view = myView`.